# Как можно получить еженедельный отчет за несколько лет в одной таблице в SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Имеется таблица с категориями и суммами затрат в указанные даты за 5 лет. Необходимо получить общие еженедельные суммы по каждой категории за весь период. То есть, на конец каждой недели необходимо вывести общую сумму по категории. Все это надо получить в виде одной таблицы. В этом и загвоздка у меня. Мой скрипт выводит каждую пару значений в виде отдельной таблицы из одной строки. Скрипт следующий

```
DECLARE @i INT = 2; -- Инкремент AccountID
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME;
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME;
DECLARE @LastDate DATETIME = (SELECT TOP 1 TransactDate FROM TempTransactions ORDER BY TransactDate DESC);
    WHILE @i <= 3
      BEGIN
        SET @StartDate = '20120101'
        SET @EndDate = '20120107'
        WHILE @EndDate <= @LastDate
          BEGIN
                SELECT S.AccountID, SUM(Baks) As Summa
                FROM (
                SELECT O.TransactDate, O.AccountID, (O.Amount/CONVERT(MONEY, REPLACE(Col2, ',', '.'))) AS Baks 
                FROM (
                SELECT T.AccountID, T.Amount, T.TransactDate, R.Col2 
                FROM TransactsAndRates.dbo.TempTransactions T
                INNER JOIN TransactsAndRates.dbo.Rates R ON T.TransactDate = R.Col1) AS O
                WHERE O.AccountID = @i) AS S
                WHERE S.TransactDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
                GROUP BY S.AccountId
            SET @StartDate = DATEADD(DAY, 7, @StartDate)
            SET @EndDate = DATEADD(DAY, 7, @EndDate)
          END
    SET @i += 1
    END
```

Как мне правильно вертикально "склеить" эти результаты в одну таблицу?
Может я не тем путем иду.

В результате указанного скрипта у меня получаются множество таблиц вида

```
AccountID |Summa    |
---------------------
2         |237.1244 |
```

Изначально данные берутся из таблицы вида

```
TransactDate |Amount     |AccountID |
-------------|-----------|----------|
01-01-2012   |11506.0000 |2         |
01-01-2012   |8899.0000  |2         |
02-01-2012   |39.0000    |2         |
03-01-2012   |238.0000   |2         |
04-01-2012   |10023.0000 |2         |
04-01-2012   |565.0000   |2         |
06-01-2012   |357.0000   |2         |
09-01-2012   |10761.0000 |2         |
09-01-2012   |446.0000   |2         |
09-01-2012   |813.0000   |2         |
09-01-2012   |531.0000   |2         |
11-01-2012   |3597.0000  |2         |
12-01-2012   |2068.0000  |2         |
13-01-2012   |10706.0000 |2         |
13-01-2012   |187.0000   |2         |
13-01-2012   |11227.0000 |2         |
14-01-2012   |3019.0000  |2         |
14-01-2012   |969.0000   |2         |
18-01-2012   |1989.0000  |2         |
19-01-2012   |204.0000   |2         |
19-01-2012   |7879.0000  |2         |
20-01-2012   |483.0000   |2         |
```

Желаемый результат

```
StartDate | EndDate  | AccountID |Summa    |
-------------------------------------------
01.07.2012|07.01.2012| 2         |237.1244 |
08.07.2012|15.01.2012| 2         |557.244  |
16.07.2012|23.01.2012| 2         |426.44   |
16.07.2012|23.01.2012| 3         |100.789  |
```

Примерно такая, но значительно больше конечно.

Comment: пример данных исходной таблицы и желаемого результата в студию

Comment: чтобы "вертикально склеить"  можно например эти данные не выводить, а вставлять во временную таблицу/табличную переменную а потом в конце сделать из нее один общий селект. Это применительно к вашему текущему решению с циклом.

Comment: @teran можете применительно к моему скрипту поправки указать для реализации того, что вы сказали?

Comment: определить табличку куда вставлять `declare @x table (acc int, baks float, sd datetime, ed datetime)`, потом перед вашим селектом сделать `insert into @x select s.accountId, sum(baks), @startDate, @endDate ... (и остальной ваш запрос ) `, а в самом конце всего `select * from @x`

Comment: @teran Попробую. Спасибо.

Comment: в любом случае, лучше бы привести исходные данные для задачи, т.к. вероятно тут может быть решение и без использования циклов.

Comment: Я как-то пробовал тут примеры демонстрировать, не вышло. Каким образом показать примеры таблиц?

Comment: сделайте выборку тестовых данных в SSMS в текстовый формат (results to text) и вставьте в вопрос ([edit]) как блок кода.

Comment: @teran посмотрите, пожалуйста, сейчас на вопрос. Так нормально?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Что то вроде:

```
SELECT dateadd(day, (datediff(day, '2012-01-01',TransactDate)/7)*7,'2012-01-01') as StartDate,
       dateadd(day, (datediff(day, '2012-01-01',TransactDate)/7)*7+6,'2012-01-01') as EndDate
        S.AccountID, SUM(Baks) As Summa
   ...
 group by S.AccountID, datediff(day, '2012-01-01',TransactDate)/7
```

Возможно немного подкорректировать формулы, для получения правильной даты начала или окончания нужной недели.

P.S. Если вам кажется, что для решения задачи на SQL вам требуется цикл, то с вероятностью 95% вы смотрите на задачу не с той стороны. Ибо SQL позволяет получать данные в любом разрезе без циклов, одним запросом.

Comment: я как человек, знающий только javascript и пытающийся освоить MS SQL, почему-то решил, что цикл это хороший вариант. )) Буду иметь в виду, что в SQL нужно думать совсем по-другому.

Comment: @DaniyalLukmanov Да, согласен. SQL язык совсем другой породы. В программе на любом императивном языке вы мыслите обработкой каждой строки по отдельности. SQL язык обработки данных, с ним надо представлять весь набор как единое целое, главное придумать критерий по которому фильтровать или группировать

Comment: А что у вас подразумевается под [Дата заказа]?

Comment: @DaniyalLukmanov Ой, TransactDate конечно. на первой попавшейся таблице с датами проверял :)

Comment: Mike, спасибо. Скрипт работает. Дальше уже постараюсь доработать сам, потому что там много дополнительных условий. И благодарю за пояснение по поводу того, как работать с SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант с рекурсивной CTE для получения дат:

```
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT @startdate AS datebegin, DATEADD(DAY,6,@startDate) dateend
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,dateend), DATEADD(DAY, 7, dateend) FROM cte
WHERE dateend<=@enddate)
SELECT datebegin, dateend, SUM(t.amount) amount, t.accountId FROM cte
LEFT JOIN transactions t ON t.TransactionDate BETWEEN datebegin AND dateend
GROUP BY datebegin, dateend, accountId
```

В CTE получаем семидневные периоды, потом джойним и группируем.

Comment: Вроде задачи получить пропущенные даты не было ... И главное если бы она и была, то какой accountId с ними показывать

Comment: Ну, если не нужны - поставить `inner join` вместо `left join`. С учётом того, что мы мало знаем и о задаче, и о данных - особой разницы нет.